# Badge progress indicator in review section

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review, badge-progress

In [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) section, badge progress for **Copy Editor** and **Civic Duty/Electorate** is displayed. If a user has not yet received **Strunk & White** badge then it would be good to hide the progress of **Copy Editor**.

[image]

For **Civic Duty/Electorate** it is currently fine, as progress of only one badge is displayed. If you have received **Civic Duty** then progress of **Electorate** is shown.

[image]

Comment: So what you want is just to hide the "non relevant" progress indicators?

Comment: Correct, simply hide it. Since I don't have "Strunk & White" yet so progress of "Copy Editor" is like adding noise to the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I never intended to show the "second level of badge progress" until you reached strunk & white.

Thanks for reminding me to remove it.

Comment: I can't see progress towards Electorate anymore.  I have Civic Duty, but not Strunk and White on the appropriate site.  Do I now need Strunk and White to see progress for the voting badges?  Are the voting badges no longer supposed to be shown?

Comment: @Troyen yes, by design, I want you to get strunk and white first prior to getting the other progress meters

Comment: @waffles, I looked at my new Review section on SO, but it shows almost nothing.  Did you restart things from scratch?

Comment: by design @LanceRoberts tons of stuff got two reviews so it is eliminated from the list, will amend the UI so it is clearer

Comment: This seems to not be implemented any more - I see Copy Editor progress on the review tab, even on sites where I haven't yet earned Strunk and White...