# Edited posts - How to for find out how many?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge progress indicator in review section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112401/badge-progress-indicator-in-review-section)
>   [How can I see my progress for different badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137959/how-can-i-see-my-progress-for-different-badges)

How do you find out how many posts that you have edited (to see how close to getting a badge)?

The *sandbox* method appears not to work?

If the answer is you cannot, is there any plans in the pipe line to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

To see how many posts you have edit you need to go to activity page of your profile and 
in that you need to got to suggestions , 
where you can find how many edits you have suggested 
like for you stackoverflow account

https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal?tab=activity&sort=all

there would be eight tabs and you need to go to suggestion tab

https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

when you click on suggested edit you reach here , like this

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/212916

and till now on SO you have suggested two edits

and at the downside you can see your details of your edits

**Ed Heal had 0 edit suggestions approved, and 2 edit suggestions rejected.**

Comment: How about edited posts?

Comment: are you asking about the number of posts you have edited ?

Comment: Yes - The 'copy editor' badge for example.

Comment: Ed , if we take example of your profile your edits are 0 ,  because if your edits are rejected you never edited those posts only approved number of edit would be you total number of edits

Comment: @EdHeal see yesterday i completed my 80 edits and today i got a strunk-white badge  http://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white?userid=766108

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers here you can see the number of edits you have made and can also see the % you have made for copy editor